# Can using a CPU with higher computing power necessarily reduce the number of required logical cores under the same load?

Tags: multithreading, server, threadpool, cpu

As the single computing power of modern CPUs is gradually increasing (the physical core and logical computing power are increasing synchronously), how to better determine the required number of threads when configuring the number of threads in multi-threaded tasks?

Considering a typical traditional server scenario that responds to requests in a multi-threaded mode, does it mean that when the throughput of the logic core doubles, I can complete the same task with half of the threads while keeping the response latency of the service unchanged?

Comment: Short answer is No.  It depends on all sorts of factors that affect a "typical server scenario" in different ways ... depending on the *actual* scenario.  The practical way to deal with this is to make a rough estimate of the number of threads needed, and then *adjust* the number to tune performance.

Comment: Also, note that response times are going to depend on the load; i.e. the number requests received per second.  As the load approaches the server's effective capacity, response times will increase. (If you really want to understand, get a math text book that covers queuing theory.)

Comment: Note that speed of individual cores grows a lot less than for example two decades ago. Most of the performance growth these days comes from using more cores.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you for your answer, that's exactly what I need. I hope to have a reliable mathematical model that provides a preliminary evaluation of the expected performance at different thread counts, thereby reducing the workload of actual testing and knowing the correct direction for thread adjustment.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, I completely agree with your point of view. Because the growth of single core computing power is another trend that distinguishes it from multi-core, we would like to examine the impact of this issue on thread pool configuration. Is there any reliable research on this topic now?

Comment: *"I hope to have a reliable mathematical model that provides a preliminary evaluation of the expected performance at different thread counts, thereby reducing the workload of actual testing and knowing the correct direction for thread adjustment."* - I don't think that is feasible.  The best you could hope for is an empirical model derived from >measuring< the effect of changing thread pool sizes, work loads, etcetera.  It is far more practical to skip the hard work of creating a model and just tune the thread pool size.